# Two Python Version conflict in Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 issue: ImportError: No module

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-11.10

I installed python 2.7.5 using make install not altinstall

Previously it was 2.7.2+

now when i run python it gives

```
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I know there are already entries related to that here. But I dont have virtualenv installed neither did i have before.

If I run `python2.7`
It runs perfectly.
Now when I am trying to import a library like mysqldb it says the module doesnt exist.
i installed it before installing python2.7.

What is the solution? Should I uninstall the whole python or rather how should I uninstall python2.7.5 only or should i keep that? If I keep that then how can i import those modules?

** **Latest UPDATE****

```
me@me:/usr/local/bin$ dir python2*
python2  python2-config  python2.7  python2.7-config
```

AND:

```
/usr/local/bin$ ls -l
total 1776
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     101 Jul 17 20:17 2to3
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root    7223 Mar 31 20:47 config_data
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     299 Jul 18 20:53 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     307 Jul 18 20:53 easy_install-2.7
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      99 Jul 17 20:17 idle
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root    3910 Mar 31 20:47 json_pp
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root     487 Mar 31 20:47 package-stash-conflicts
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     281 Jul 17 19:51 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     289 Jul 17 19:51 pip-2.7
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root      84 Jul 17 20:17 pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 18 23:04 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Jul 18 23:04 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Jul 18 23:04 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jul 18 23:04 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1737376 Jul 18 23:03 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1674 Jul 18 23:04 python2.7-config
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   18547 Jul 17 20:17 smtpd.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     316 Jul 18 21:10 virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     324 Jul 18 21:10 virtualenv-2.7
```

would reinstalling this solve the problem of getting and running the default 2.7.2+ in ubuntu back?: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/python-defaults/2.7.2-7ubuntu2

*** Prior UPDATE***

Now I can run python from bash

Here is the new problem. and it is with every module that I install using pip.

existing modules from lib can be imported but newly installed ones cant be:

```
me:~$ sudo pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-1.2.3.tar.gz (348kB): 348kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Installing collected packages: requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
me:~$ python -i
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 17 2013, 20:16:12)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
```

After checking version of python it is running locally, for conflict issues:

```
me:~$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 17 2013, 20:16:12)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
me:~$ sudo python
[sudo] password for me:
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 17 2013, 20:16:12)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
me:~$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
me:~$ sudo which python
/usr/local/bin/python
me:~$ sudo which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
me:~$ which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

I think its running the same. and then..

```
me:/usr/local/bin$ dir python2.7
python2.7
me:/usr/local/bin$ cd /usr/bin
me:/usr/bin$ dir python2.7
python2.7

me:/bin$ cd /usr/bin
me:/usr/bin$ dir python
python

me:/usr/local/bin$ dir python
python
me:/usr/local/bin$ dir python2.7
python2.7
```

Also check following:

```
~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Ok now I installed virtualenv
and this is what i did

```
(foldername)me@me:~/caller$ sudo pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
(foldername)me@me:~/caller$ python -i
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And NOW we can see that 2.7.2+ is back again! So what is happening now??
what is wrong?

Uninstalling older python from linux is not recommended. So how can i run virtualenv with 2.7.5 on it and not 2.7.2+ ?!

Answer (score 2):

When installing python use the following steps
using prefix to specify the installation directory

```
 ./configure --prefix=/scratch/bin/
 make
 sudo make install
```

Then everytime u run a new Terminal u have specify

```
export PATH="$PATH:/scratch/bin/"
```

to tell where is the installation directory of Python

This way u can use any number of pythons

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it using apt-get or built from sources?

If built from sources, are you sure the installation has finished successfully? Usually in order to build Python from sources one has to do the following steps

- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install` (`sudo` might not be required, but the make script will attempt to change files in `/usr/` directory.

in your python sources directory. The last command, amongst others, copies python to the `/usr/` directory. If you want to have it installed somewhere else you'd have to pass `--path=XXX` (if i'm not mistaken) to `./configure`.

Comment: like i said make install is what i did. before that all the steps as u've stated. Yes but I did not use --path=XXX or /usr and im afraid is it that which caused it to reside beside python. there is python and python2.7 there now

Comment: Do you get it immediately after running `python` in your shell?

Comment: ok now there is an update.python is running but the problem is with importing modules.check update on main question

Comment: Try checking whether both `python` and `sudo python` point to the same binary with `which python` and `sudo which python`. If not, that's the reason for your pip issue - `sudo pip install` installs the package into global python, whilst `python` launches your local copy

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is a Python program. When you run `pip` from the command line, it uses a particular Python executable to run the program. `pip` will install modules in a location where *that* Python executable can find them.

When you run `sudo pip install some_package`, the OS looks at the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to determine what Python executable to run.

Type `which pip` and look at the first line in the file to see which python executable it is linked to.

To install packages for your new python2.7.5, you could either [install a new `pip`.](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) Or, you could just run `/usr/local/bin/python pip ...`, but I think the easiest way to manage multiple python installations is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).

If you use virtualenv (which I'd highly recommend), then a new `pip` is automatically installed since it is one of its dependencies.
If you go this route, I'd recommend installing [virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper) too.

If you install pip globally, [notice the line](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

```
python get-pip.py
```

or

```
python setup.py install
```

The python executable you use on this line sets the "link" between that version of pip and that version of python.

---

**How to use checkinstall to remove a custom-built Python:**

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libgdbm-dev liblzma-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get build-dep python

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2
tar xvjf Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2
cd Python-2.7.5
# inspect the options
./configure --help  
./configure
make
make test
sudo checkinstall -D --fstrans=no make install

# Accept the default answers EXCEPT that you MUST change the name to something
# other than python. That way, the name of your custom package does not conflict
# with the name of Ubuntu's "python" package

        Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]: 
        Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 2
        Enter new name: 
        >> python275

        Copying files to the temporary directory...OK
        # wait, wait, wait...

# python2.7.5 is now installed in /usr/local/bin
# remove it with:
sudo dpkg -r python275
```

Comment: I would like to if I uninstall both pythons and reinstalling the 2.7.5 would it solve my problem?

Comment: this is your post right: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1216379&page=2 should i go ahead with this?

Comment: it gave me:  sudo dpkg -r python
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python:(list of depende....) and finally: Errors were encountered while processing:
 python

Comment: python_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb this is the package created

Comment: would reinstalling this solve the problem of getting and running the default 2.7.2+ in ubuntu back?: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/python-defaults/2.7.2-7ubuntu2

Comment: `sudo dpkg -r python` is asking the system to remove the standard Ubuntu package `python`. Whatever you do, do not remove this, as doing so would  break your installation of Ubuntu. Try instead `sudo dpkg -r python_2.7.5-1_amd64`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to create a virtualenv environment using python2.7.5, try `virtualenv myenv -p /usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: check the latest * Latest UPDATE** section: i did that after ur above cmd

Comment: I see a list of /usr/local/bin. What is that supposed to tell us?

Comment: conflicting vers of easy_install and pip and python->python2 and python2->python2.7 is that something that gives lead to resolving this issue? and would that help in anyway to uninstall the latest ver of python? ultimately easy_install is also giving problems because of that version conflict

Comment: I don't understand your situation very well, but I don't see any inherent problem with the files in /usr/bin/local. If you really want to get rid of it and try again, however, have you tried `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/python_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb` followed by `sudo dpgk -r python_2.7.5-1_amd64`? What happened? Were there any error messages?

Comment: it gave me: sudo dpkg -r python dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python:(list of depende....) and finally: Errors were encountered while processing: python while sudo dpkg -i /path/to/python_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb says just to use package name.not python_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb

Comment: I've added step-by-step instructions on how to remove a custom-built Python using checkinstall. Note that you have to change the name of the package to something other than `python` so the checkinstall package name will not conflict with the Ubuntu package called `python`. That way, when you run `sudo dpkg -r python275` Ubuntu does not think you are asking it to remove the system package (eek!)

Comment: im upgrading to ubuntu 13.04. let me see if it uses my last and latest installed python 2.7 ver by default or not. i will revert back to you on this soon